# Repeat last selection in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, workflow, selections, shortcuts

Repeating the last selection can be useful. For example:

- Sometimes you apply changes to several selected objects simultaneously. To properly appreciate the result and avoid clutter, it is necessary to temporarily deselect, and then select again if further changes are needed.
- Sometimes you apply changes to a selection and accidentally click on the background or something else, hence losing the selection. If the selection were really complicated you should have created a group for it, but if it is just a few objects you may feel that it is not appropriate to create a group.

Is there a way to recover or repeat the last selection in Inkscape? I have seen a couple of threads on other forums such as [this one](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic0819.html?t=2962) and [this one](https://alpha.inkscape.org/vectors/www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopicc9c7.html?t=6871) that seem to indicate that it is not possible, but they are a decade old, so new features may have been added since then.

Comment: Illustrator allows a user to save a selection fro recalling later. It has to be manually saved though... not sure if Inkscape has anything similar. In *most* instances merely **undo** if you need to reselect something that's been mistakenly deselected.

Comment: Undoing is also the approach that first came to my mind, but as far as I am aware, undoing in Inkscape does not recover the previous selection (at least in the version I am using, `Inkscape 0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to save selections, or redo them. Also Inkscape's undo history doesn't record selections, only physical moves/edits/changes.

A possible workaround if you don't want to use groups, is to use layers instead. In the Objects panel you can lock layers you don't want to be selectable, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>(select all) will only select objects on unlocked layers.

You can also lock objects individually if having everything on separate layers is overkill.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Posting feature requests for software on StackExchange is not a good use of everyone's time. Please use the appropriate tracker for this at https://inkscape.org/report .

If you use CSS classes, though, you can create selection sets that are re-selectable. But whether you use them depends a lot on the purpose and structure of the drawing and upon your workflow.

Comment: I am not posting a feature request. I am asking if this feature already exists because I am a recent user of Inkscape (1 week). I have seen this done in other programs, but I don't know if it is possible to repeat selections in Inkscape. When I have asked if a feature would be useful in a different post, it hasn't been because I am requesting that feature either, but rather because I want to learn about the appropriate workflow. If I miss a feature, but more experienced people don't, then there's probably a different way of doing things I haven't realized.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry then. When your selection is static, use CSS classes. When your selection changes frequently, make a feature request.